# Template interface singleton

Tags: c++

I was hoping to use an interface to make a generic template class I can add to any other class to easily create singletons. (By easily create singletons I mean avoid having to re-write the 6 lines for `GetInstance`)

```
template <class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
   static T* GetInstance();
};

template<class T>
inline T* Singleton<T>::GetInstance()
{
 static T* myInst;

 if (!myInst)
 {
    myInst = new T();
 }

 return(myInst);
}
```

The only issue is that with this to work I have to have the constructor for the class be public, which I would like to avoid as it sort of ruins the Singleton design pattern.

Is there a solution I may not be aware of to get an instance for the generic type without having a public constructor? I do realise this might be a stupid question but I would really like this class to work.

Thanks

Comment: Make the actual `Singleton<T>` class a `friend` of `T`?

Comment: Your singleton isn't thread safe, stop using pointers inside the class. That would be 2 lines in the function.

Comment: Public constructor is not an issue. The issues are: Inability to invoke constructor with arguments, lazy initialization, raw pointer, resource leak.

Comment: A small side note. Singletons are often frowned upon. And honestly whenever I see a singleton I immediately suspect a faulty design. So if you have so many singletons that you need to create a helper class to save you writing the 6 lines, I would reconsider my design. :) With that said as one already noted it is not thread safe, and even if it was I would consider not using primitive pointers.

Comment: @TommyAndersen Cheers for the feedback! I've only got 3 singleton classes at the moment, this was more of a "could it be done?" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your singleton should look differently as yours isn't thread safe. Then there are at least 2 solutions. First, is to make a particular instantiation a friend, so it would look something like this:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T* GetInstance();
};

template<class T>
T* Singleton<T>::GetInstance()
{
    static T myInst;
    return &myInst;
}

class Test
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello!\n";
    }
private:
    Test() = default;
    friend class Singleton<Test>;
};
```

That would require the modification of the user class which isn't ideal. So we can employ another solution like this:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton: private T
{
public:
    static T* GetInstance();
private:
    using T::T;
};

template<class T>
T* Singleton<T>::GetInstance()
{
    static Singleton<T> myInst;
    return &myInst;
}

class Test
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello!\n";
    }
protected:
    Test() = default;
};
```

The only modification to the user class is making its ctor to be `protected` instead of `private` which is not a problem, in my opinion. The limitation is that the user class should not be `final`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually hadn't heard the exact term "CRTP" before so I've been able to read up on that. Also thanks for clearing up the correct way to handle singletons, I've been using pointers for far too long

Comment: For CRTP -> `class Test : public Singleton<Test>`.

Comment: You can even return reference instead of pointer for `GetInstance`. and delete copy/move assignment/constructor for `Singleton`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I left the interface as is. Some people prefer pointers. And you are correct about CRTP, removed it.